# Java won't draw my image when method is called using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, image, graphics, awt

I have this flower program where it is supposed to drop flowers from above.... I need it to wait a few seconds then call the method to drop the flower. I know the method runs because i have it print out the falling y values. But it won't draw it on the screen. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here is some of the code...

```
    //Ignore starting here
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.util.Random;
    //Ignore ending here

    public class RedFlower implements ActionListener{
        Timer time;
        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("graphics//flowers//red_flower.png");
        Image flower = i.getImage();
        int y, x;
        int dy = 1;
        public void dropFlower(){
            Random rnd = new Random();
            y = 50;
            x = rnd.nextInt(1216);
            time = new Timer(5, this);
            time.start();
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){// used for stoping the timer when off the screen
    int checky = y++;
    if(checky < 720){
        y++;
    }else{
        time.stop();
    }
    System.out.println(y);

}
//everything after this is what i call in the other method
    public Image getImage(){
    return flower;
}
public int getX(){
    return x;
}
public int getY(){
    return y;
}
    }
```

Now this is my drawing code...

```
    public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2d.drawImage(rf.getImage(), rf.getX(), rf.getY(), null);// rf is what i called the method
    g2d.drawImage(sc.getImage(), sc.getX(), sc.getY(), null);//this is the basket that you control
}
```

Also a weird thing is when i make pressing a button call the method it works but not when the thread runs it...

Comment: Your actionPerformed method does nothing, the reason it works when you push a button is because a button event causes your frame to update and repaint. Try add `your_component.repaint();` to your actionPreformed method just below `y++;`

Comment: 1) `g2d.drawImage(rf.getImage(), rf.getX(), rf.getY(), null);` should probably be `g2d.drawImage(rf.getImage(), rf.getX(), rf.getY(), this);` 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("graphics//flowers//red_flower.png");`  Uggh..  1) No need for `//` (on any system), Windows will understand `/`. 2) An `ImageIcon` fails silently if the path is wrong.  Use `ImageIO`.  3) While this might work (loading the image as a `File`) in your IDE, it will not work at time of deployment.  Use `Class.getResource("/path/to/image")` to get an URL.

Comment: Updating every 5 milliseconds is overkill, you may also not be giving the repaint manager and EDT time to actually breath.  You've got your animation updating at 200fps...try something closer to 40/100 milliseconds (on top of everything else)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double slashes.

```
 ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("graphics/flowers/red_flower.png");
```

Comment: I doubt that will have any effect (though it should be changed), see my 2nd comment.